# Removing white background-mesh from export-fig output

Tags: matlab, pdf

I am making a surf-plot with MATLAB, here is a MWE:

```
[xx,yy]  = meshgrid(-1:0.025:1,-1:0.025:1);
tst = sin(xx.*yy);        
surf(ones(size(xx)), yy, xx, tst(1:end, 1:end), 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

I want to outout this as a vectorized PDF for which I use `export_fig`:

```
export_fig( 'asd.pdf', '-q100', '-m3')
```

However, this produces a PDF with a white mesh in the background, it is visible in this attachment:

[image]

As I understand it, this is an artifact of aliasing due to the PDF-viewer. Is there a way to output the PDF using `export-fig` such that this undesired background-mesh disappears?

Comment: Just as a note to the code itself:  `tst(1:end,1:end)` is exactly equal to `tst`. You're calling the full matrix anyway, no need to specify the indices, like you're doing already with `xx` and `yy`. (For higher dimensional matrices this behaviour does change, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

You can export the picture in eps format `print('myfiglocation','-depsc')` and then there are many ways you can convert it into a pdf while retaining its vectorised format.

Here is what I tried:

1. Export the picture into eps format.
2. Insert it into a new MS Word file.
3. Save as Adobe PDF (using Acrobat extension)

The result isn't perfect though as the colour appears to be washed and the axis labels are bold.

I tried to export the picture using adobe illustrator to retain the quality of the eps file. However, the white lines are present this time, although they disappear after zoom in on the picture. I think you should either change the file format or reduce the picture quality so PDF viewer can properly handle it.

The result:

[image]